# Music In The House Of The Undying

Tags: game-of-thrones, soundtrack

When Danaerys "reunites" with Drogo in the House of the Undying in S2E10: "Valar Morghulis" what is the wind instrument playing? Some kind of horn or flute thing?

Answer (score 2):

I have no authoritative conformation on this, but it sounds like a Tin Whistle<sup>(1)</sup>, made popular in James Horner's Braveheart soundtrack, & also used in Lord of the Rings.

The fact that I'm not able to hear where the player actually takes a breath makes me think it might be a sampled instrument, similar to [Embertone's Shire Whistle](http://www.embertone.com/instruments/shirewhistle.php) - nice solo [demo here](https://soundcloud.com/embertone/embertone-howard-shore-shire?in=embertone/sets/embertone-shire-whistle) which includes a couple of pitch-bends similar to those in the Game of Thrones soundtrack.

*S2E10: "Valar Morghulis" - Timestamp approx 50:45*

<sup>(1)</sup>The [Tin Whistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_whistle) goes by many names, tin whistle, penny whistle, flageolet

Answer (score 0):

It was an Armenian duduk, it actually had become popular by Hans Zimmer at the era of making Gladiator.

Djivan Gasparyan is the Armenian composer who plays this beautiful instrument there:

Peace.